# Convert multimap<Key,Value> to vector<vector<Value>>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I need to convert an `std::unordered_multimap<Key,T>` to an `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. I need to do this because my program will need to sort all the data, and maps can't be sorted. An example:

```
// Map:
{ "A", 1 },
{ "A", 3 },
{ "A", 2 },
{ "B", 5 }, 
{ "B", 2 },

// Map converted to vector<vector<Value>>:
{ 1, 3, 2 }, 
{ 5, 2 }
```

Right now I have this code which works. But I'm wondering if it's the best way to do it.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>    

int main()
{
    typedef std::string Key_t;
    typedef int Value_t;
    typedef std::unordered_multimap<Key_t, Value_t> Map_t;

    const Map_t map = {
        { "A", 1 }, 
        { "A", 3 }, 
        { "A", 2 },
        { "B", 5 }, 
        { "B", 2 },
    };

    std::vector< std::vector< Value_t > > output;

    for ( Map_t::const_iterator it = map.cbegin(); it != map.cend(); )
    {
        std::vector< Value_t > temp;
        const Map_t::const_iterator end = map.upper_bound( it->first );
        for ( ; it != end; ++it )
            temp.push_back( it->second );

        output.push_back( temp );
    }

    // Print the result
    for ( const std::vector< Value_t >& values : output )
    {
        for ( const Value_t& value : values )
            std::cout << value << " ";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 3 2
5 2
```

So, now I'm wondering if there's a faster/better way.

Comment: I think `typedef std::string Value_t;` is supposed to be for an integral type (e.g., `int`)..

Comment: @JamesAdkison Oh, right. Fixed.

Comment: Nope, checked again, there's no `upper_bound` in the standard's specification of `unordered_map` or `unordered_multimap`. Sure you're using the unordered variant? (The code also doesn't compile with libstdc++ or libc++ for me, after fixing the missing `<vector>` include.)

Comment: The [unordered map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) is documented as having an `equal_range` function but not upper or lower bound, which makes since as it would rely on a sorted order.

Comment: @Xeo I am 100% sure I'm using `unordered_multimap` and my code is compiling and working perfectly on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Now I'm really interested how they implemented that. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual multimap iteration should work here:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> out;

for (auto it1 = m.begin(), it2 = it1, end = m.end(); it1 != end; it1 = it2)
{
    out.emplace_back();
    for ( ; it1->first == it2->first; ++it2)
    {
        out.back().push_back(it2->second);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need this function call out.emplace_back();, Doesn't just out.push_back(it2->second) sufficient?

Comment: @Steephen: First append an empty vector to the outer vector of vectors, then append items to that new inner vector.

Answer (score 2):

here's my attempt.

proof is here: http://goo.gl/JVpHw9

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    typedef std::string Key_t;
    typedef int Value_t;
    typedef std::unordered_multimap<Key_t, Value_t> Map_t;

    const Map_t map = {
        { "A", 1 }, 
        { "A", 3 }, 
        { "A", 2 },
        { "B", 5 }, 
        { "B", 2 },
    };

    std::vector< std::vector< Value_t > > output;

    for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); )
    {
        auto er = map.equal_range(it->first);
        auto tmp = std::vector< Value_t >{};
        for( ; it != er.second ; ++it) {
            tmp.push_back(it->second);
        };
        output.push_back(std::move(tmp));
    }
    // Print the result
    for ( const std::vector< Value_t >& values : output )
    {
        for ( const Value_t& value : values )
            std::cout << value << " ";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

int main () {
    std::unordered_multimap<std::string, int> map;
    map = {
        { "A", 1 }, 
        { "A", 3 }, 
        { "A", 2 },
        { "B", 5 }, 
        { "B", 2 },
    };

    std::vector<int> values;

    std::transform(map.begin(), map.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(values),
                   [](std::pair<std::string, int> element) {
                       return element.second;
                   });

    for (auto const& value : values) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```